# Quick way to prototype web graphs derived from SQL database

Tags: sql, c, web, graph, prototype

I have statistics for a project stored in a MySQL database and looking for a quick way to prototype a webpage which graphs various relationships in the data, using bar graph, line graph, pie chart, etc. I found something called "Dashing", but seems to use something called "coffeescript" which I'd rather not learn in my short time frame (~1 week).

Does anyone know of any good packages/frameworks that can help out with the job? If I could do it using only C/C++/obj-C it would be ideal, though Java is possible as well.

Answer (score 0):

I decided on using PHP/Apache/MySQL and the Jpgraph PHP graphing framework.